# Matrix L2 Norm Definition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Might be an odd question, but why the l2 norm of a matrix is defined the way it is defined?
Given the definition,

$$\|A\|_2 = \text{max} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$$

Specifically:

- why is it the **maximum** of the argument rather than the **minimum**, for example?
- Also, why do we divide by the l2 norm of a vector?
- Also, why do we need a **vector** to define a norm of a matrix at all?

I'm not a mathematician, so if these questions seem weird, sorry in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: For your suggestion: check if your proposal gives a norm on the space of matrices. As for the $\ell_2$-norm, think of its geometric meaning.